# Show result Select *

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I done my SQL request like this in my model.php :

```
public function getUserForAdmin() { 
    $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT prenom AS prenomUFA, nom AS nomUFA, email AS emailUFA, cp AS cpUFA FROM user');
    return $arrayUser['prenomUFA'];
}
```

In my index.php I call it like this

```
$userForAdmin = $user->getUserForAdmin();
echo $userForAdmin['prenomUFA'];
```

With this I have just the first letter of my prenom fields result...

Output of my array :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => hj [userForAdmin] => 69570 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => officiel@coucou.fr [userForAdmin] => 69570 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => officiel@coucou.fr [userForAdmin] => 69570 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => hjkjk [userForAdmin] => 69570 )
    [4] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => officiel@coucou.fr [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [5] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => hjkhjk [userForAdmin] => 69570 )   
    [6] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => jkljl [email] => jkljl@fgfg.fr [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [7] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => fgdfg [email] => dfgfdg@dsdfg.hfg [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [8] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => ghjg [email] => ghj@fddfg.fr [userForAdmin] => ghj ) 
    [9] => Array ( [prenom] => ghj [nom] => ghjghj [email] => ghgh@dfgdfg.fra [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [10] => Array ( [prenom] => hjkhk [nom] => hjkhjk [email] => hjk@sdfdf.fr [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [11] => Array ( [prenom] => cvbcb [nom] => cvbcvb [email] => cvbcv@dfgdfg.fr [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [12] => Array ( [prenom] => jhk [nom] => hjkhjk [email] => hjhjk@dfgdfg.fr [userForAdmin] => ) 
    [13] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => cghjghj [userForAdmin] => 45645 )   
    [14] => Array ( [prenom] => Coline [nom] => [email] => ghj [userForAdmin] => 44545 ) 
)
```

Comment: $arrayUser is array but $arrayUser['userForAdmin'] is not an array. It is the value at 'userForAdmin' key in the array. So echo '<p>'.$userForAdmin.'</p>'; seems fine to me.

Comment: @colinec Request you to please elaborate what you want to output. Your code says that it is fetching rows from database table named 'user'. Then you are storing first row of result set in variable $arrayUser. And in the next statement you are returning value stored in 'cp' column (alias of which you have given 'userForAdmin' in the query) using  $arrayUser['userForAdmin'].

Comment: Sorry, I want to output all my fields ask from my SELECT. Like : prenom, nom, email and cp. I realised that my AS was just tooking my CP. If I put an AS to all my fields, how to return them in the fonction ?

Comment: To return the AS's you may have to look at how `getArray()` is designed to return the data.

Comment: @colinec Please try the code that I have posted in answer section. It fulfills your requirement.

Comment: I answered to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getUserForAdmin() { 
    $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT prenom AS prenomUFA, nom AS nomUFA, email AS emailUFA, cp AS cpUFA FROM user');
    return $arrayUser;
}
```

In index.php call it like this  -

```
$userForAdmin = $user->getUserForAdmin();
foreach($userForAdmin as $rows)
{  
    echo '<p>'.$rows['prenomUFA'].'</p><br>';
    echo '<p>'.$rows['nomUFA'].'</p><br>';
    echo '<p>'.$rows['emailUFA'].'</p><br>';
    echo '<p>'.$rows['cpUFA'].'</p><br>';
}
```

Above code outputs all the values.

Answer (score 2):

In order for to return the entire array from the function do this -

```
public function getUserForAdmin() { 
    $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT prenom, nom, email, cp AS userForAdmin FROM user');
    return $arrayUser;
}
```

Call it like so -

```
$userForAdmin = $user->getUserForAdmin();
print_r($userForAdmin); // testing to see what is in the array
```

It appears that `getArray()` returns an array of arrays and that your `AS` alias' are returned properly. To access an individual item you have to do it this way:

```
echo $userForAdmin[0]['userForAdmin']; // note the specification used in multidimensional arrays
echo $userForAdmin[0]['prenom']; // has no 'AS' alias
echo $userForAdmin[0]['nom'];
echo $userForAdmin[0]['email'];
```

You may want to look at `getArray()` so that it returns something more convenient to work with.

Comment: Actually my AS userForAdmin just take my "cp" field. So when I try print_r($userForAdmin) to show all fields, It shows just the "cp"

Comment: So what is the issue then @colinec?

Comment: If I put an AS after all fields like SELECT prenom AS prenomUser, nom AS nomUser ... How to tell to my return that I want him to return all my fields ?

Comment: Ah, if that is the issue why didn't you show that in the OP?

Comment: something like this : return $arrayUser['prenomUser'], $arrayUser['nomUser']... But this is not possible

Comment: your print_r show me all what I have in my array, so it's cool. But, echo $userForAdmin['userForAdmin']; alone doesn't show anything...

Comment: Is 'userForAdmin' in the array?

Comment: @colinec In your updated code the line return $arrayUser['userForAdmin']; will not return anything. It is incorrect. $arrayUser is array that contains result set of rows and 'userForAdmin' is alias of column named 'cp' you can not give it like this $arrayUser['userForAdmin']. You need to return $arrayUser within the function body. And in index.php -- $userForAdmin = $user->getUserForAdmin(); then iterate through $userForAdmin to get the values.

Comment: Yes, so logically, I would just have to echo $arrayUser ? because it contains all my results.

Comment: @colinec Yes. You need to return $arrayUser. Please see my comment given above yours.

Comment: Ok. You can look at my OP, without the AS and with return $arrayUser.

Comment: It is returning a multidimensional array ($arrayUser) which you have to parse to get the results you want. See my updated post.

Comment: Ok I seen it. But userForAdmin is just for cp, not for all fields

Comment: Right. You would have to add an alias for the other columns using `AS`

Comment: Yes. Ashish code works for me, you can take a look if you want.